# 14.04: Volume keyboard shortcut stopped working

Tags: sound, 14.04, shortcut-keys, volume-control

Once i have started up the ubuntu 14.04 (upgraded from 13.10 and 13.04) the media keyboard shortcuts was not working.

As i didn't know why i tryed to set the volume down shortcut again (it was set correctly when i started the keyboard shortcuts settings), which didn't have any effect, so i have rebooted the system. After the reboot the shortcut i didn't reset (volume up) works perfectly, however even after reseting the volume down shortcut again it doesn't work.

Is there any way to fix this thing?

I have also tried unseting the shortcut and setting it again.

The system is up-to-date

```
Linux Lyra 3.13.0-24-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 2 23:30:00 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Curious thing: Now when i press the volume down, and VLC player has focus, the volume of the VLC player goes down and when i press volume up, the system volume goes up

This might be duplicate of [Ubuntu 14.04 LTS - Volume control keys](https://askubuntu.com/questions/468612/ubuntu-14-04-lts-volume-control-keys) but it is not answered, and also he sais he can't use the buttons at all, however i can use the volume up without issues

Comment: Do i have to live with broken shortut until i reinstall ubuntu?!

Comment: Nice one, ubuntu... :-(