# Macbook pro volume keys not working

Tags: sound, keyboard, shortcut-keys, macbook

Macbook Pro 5,4 volume hot keys no longer change the volume. Numerous reboots, remapping of the keys in system settings, still not working. mute key works fine but volume up and down are not responsive. The actual keystrokes register ie: keyboard settings.

This happened suddenly without rebooting a couple weeks ago after previously working without issue in 13.10 then 14.04 for a little while/

Comment: I have the same issue. I reseted the pram, rebooted a couple of times, remapping of keyboard shortcuts, turned off to use fn key on settings. I don't know what more to do

Comment: This [guy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/468612/ubuntu-14-04-lts-volume-control-keys) has the same issue as well. I was able to temporarily remap the volume controls to alt+super+down/up but this can't be permanent. I used xev to confirm that the keystrokes are registering and they seem to be working fine.

Comment: What Ubuntu version you used? Previously I have this problem with 12.04, but in 14.04, volume keys work well. Did you try Fn+Volume keys?

Comment: Did you go over [these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro) again after you upgraded?

Comment: This was a while ago and I can't remember specifically what I did. After this I did switch from Unity to Gnome 3 and probably set the volume keys in the keyboard settings. The machine is probably still on 14.04 but doesn't get used often enough but everything does currently work under Gnome.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on Mint18 with Cinnamon..
In synaptic package manager search for "pulse" then

mark:

- `pulseaudio-module-x11` for install
- `lib cvc0` for reinstall
- `gir1.2-cvc-1.0` for reinstall

hit apply

in terminal: `sudo alsa force-reload`

restart your machine.

The prob for me was that the keys were correctly bound and the OS was picking up the presses, but something was stopping it from being used for sound by cinnamon, just needed to reinstall normal settings